# use old USB digital camera as webcam?

Tags: webcam

I've got an old average point-and-click digital camera that I don't use anymore, but I wonder if I could reuse it as a webcam by plugging it as a USB device into an Ubuntu computer?

Where can I find out about this? What shall I look for to know if the camera can act as a webcam?

Comment: I have done this a few times. (Buying digital cameras from charity shops for a few UK pounds.) Some digital cameras can do this, some can't. You need to look at the manual to see if you camera has this capability. If you don't have a paper copy you might find it online.

Comment: I shall try that. What shall I look for to know if the camera can act as a webcam?

Comment: Can you specify which camera you would want to use?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).