# Using a digital camera ( Canon) as webcam

Tags: webcam, camera

I can't use my digital camera ( Canon ixus 160) as webcam 
is there an application for that ?
or just in the settings?

Comment: Add more info. You must be getting some error or something.

Comment: Are there any clues in the manual that this is possible? A similar question has been asked before http://askubuntu.com/questions/53889/use-old-usb-digital-camera-as-webcam but it was closed (for no good reason imho). Also something like that is done in this http://www.moreno.marzolla.name/software/linux-webcam-server/ tutorial.

Answer (score 32):

Here's another solution.

List of *gphoto2* supported cameras: http://gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php

You need install *gphoto*, *v4l2loopback-utils* and *ffmpeg*.

Then

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

and

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

Now you have webcamera from your digital camera.

Comment: I get this error (cut at top):
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1056x704, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[swscaler @ 0x559c14f77de0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[v4l2 @ 0x559c14f42fc0] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
➜  ~

Comment: @noreabu if you have other webcams, the `/dev/video1` may not be the loopback device. You can check type of devices with `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`

Comment: It worked for me... but the resolution is 1056x704. Is it possible to change it to a 16:9 resolution, such as 720p? I am using a Cannon T3i and this option is available on Entangle... however I don't know how to change your command to switch to a different aspect ratio

Answer (score 22):

This can be done but requires a number of steps. First, you must install `gphoto` and `v4l2loopback-utils`.

`sudo apt-get install gphoto2 v4l2loopback-utils`

Plug in your camera via USB (when the camera mounts automatically, unmount it). Then run `gphoto2 --abilities` to see if your camera is capable of doing this. Here's the output when connecting a Canon EOS 1200D

[image]

Then run `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback` to activate the kernel module needed to create a video device from your camera.

I've seen older tutorials on this task that use gst-launch-0.10 to achieve the next step of this task (e.g. [this one](http://blog.skhawaja.com/2015/12/use-your-dslr-camera-work-as-webcam-on.html)). I am using Ubuntu 17.04 which uses gst-launch-1.0. Below is the updated command to create a video device from your digital camera:

`gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! decodebin3 name=dec ! queue ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1`

This will create a video device in `/dev/video1`, which you can now use in programs like VLC.

If you see any errors about the device being in use you need to kill the `gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor` process by running `killall gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor`.

Comment: I get this:
`➜  ~ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! decodebin3 name=dec ! queue ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Nehme Vorschaubilder als Film in 'stdout' auf. Drücke Ctrl-C zum abbrechen.
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: »/dev/video1« ist kein Wiedergabegerät.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(642): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0:
Capabilities: 0x5200001
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...`

Comment: @noreabu sounds like a bug that you should report

Comment: Try /dev/video2

Comment: This worked via the ffmpeg answer above. I had to use `guvcview` to see the output

Comment: I'm getting `modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic`

Comment: I confirm this works well on Ubuntu 18.04 with Canon 70D. The only difference is that the device is not created by the `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback` command  in `/dev/video1`, but in `/dev/video0`. Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer! :)

Comment: Beware, the older cameras like Canon 70D limit time they can have the sensor switched on becuase it produces quite a lot of heat. On my Canon 70D, it's 30 minuts, so it's not usable for longer video calls.

Comment: I'm using a Panasonic HC-V777 on Ubuntu 18.04. When unmounting the camera and querying `gphoto2 --abilities` I get `*** Fehler (-105: »Unknown Model«) ***`. Do I have to report my camera as unsupported to the gphoto devs? On http://gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php it says `If it a USB mass storage based camera (appearing like a USB stick or USB drive) it is mounted by your operating system and not gphoto2. In this case a report to us is not necessary.` And my camera does get mounted like a mass storage device.

Comment: I posted a solution for unmounting your camera, if unmounting doesn't work via nautilus: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265670/

Answer (score 9):

I was able to get video & image recording with a Canon DSLR 600D

`sudo apt get install guvcview ffmpeg gphoto2 v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils ffmpeg`

Plug in camera, any mode seemed to work, test with the basics:

Prep

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
killall gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
```

Test

```
lsusb
gphoto2 --auto-detect
LANG=C gphoto2 --summary
LANG=C gphoto2 --list-all-config
```

Try

```
gphoto2 --capture-image
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

Visualize  (in another terminal)

`guvcview`

or

`guvcview-brlin.guvcview`

You can try different `/dev/video1` commands

There's also [EOS Movie Recorder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eos-movrec/)

Unzip this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eos-movrec/files/eos-movrec/0.3.3_beta/eos-movrec-0.3.3_beta.zip/download

```
cd eos-movrec-0.3.2_beta
sudo apt install libgphoto2-dev                                     
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
```

Comment: thanks. i use this and then capture the window in OBS "gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffplay - "

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to access the camera microphone at the same time (and make it an accessible device)?

Comment: OBS has microphone capability, and plugins that can expose the whole setup as a webccam too

Answer (score 6):

I found this very useful for me and it did work with my Canon 5D Mark 3

How to use you DSLR camera as a webcam

OBS is a great tool for live streaming and recording a presentation or training. It can also be used to create a virtual webcam to act as input to tools such as Jitsi, Skype and Zoom. Lots of us have good DSLR type cameras, and these can act as a webcam for input to OBS (and any other tool that can use a webcam source). This allows  you to use a high quality camera for the video input, and gives you the full control that you get with a digital camera. In this video, I show you how to use pretty much any camera as a webcam for OBS without any special software or hardware adapters. All you need is a camera and a USB cable. This is achieved using the combination of gphoto2, ffmpeg, and v42loopback.

1. Make sure your camera make and model is supported. You will find a list of cameras supported by this method at
   http://gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php
   Fortunately, my Canon cameras are all supported. You will need a supported camera and a USB cable to connect the camera to your computer.
2. Set your camera so that it does not automatically power off. On my Canon 6D Mark ii this is "Auto power off: Disable" on the wrench screen 2.
3. If you have back-button focus enabled, you need to set focus back the the half press of the shutter key. If you use back button-focus you already know how to do this. If you leave back-button focus on, you will get errors relating to shutter button half press.
4. If you don't have gphoto2 installed, you need to install it first.

   ```
   sudo apt install -y gphoto2
   ```
5. If you don't have the video loopback driver installed, you need to install it first.

   ```
   sudo apt install -y v4l2loopback-utils
   ```
6. If you don't have ffmpeg installed, you need to install it first.

   ```
   sudo apt install -y ffmpeg
   ```
7. Plug in your camera via USB (if the camera mounts automatically, unmount it) by selecting it in your file manager (Nautilus if you are using Gnome) and right click, and select "Unmount" from the popup menu.
8. Enable and determine the virtual video device
   First unload v4l2loopback so you can determine which device it is creating.

   ```
   sudo rmmod v4l2loopback
   ```

   Ignore any errors.
9. List all video devices so you know which one is next in line
   `ls /dev/video*`
   You will see something like
   `/dev/video0  /dev/video1`
   which indicates video devices already on my computer. If you see nothing here, then you have no video devices.
10. Activate v4l2loopback
    Run

    ```
    sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 max_buffers=2
    ```

to activate the kernel module ('loopback driver') that enables the creation of a video device from your DSLR camera.

11. List all video devices so you know which one is the one to use
    `ls /dev/video*`
    You will see something like
    `/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2`
    The last one will be the one used by the loopback driver, in this case video2.
12. TESTING
    Now you can do some testing using gphoto 2.
    List auto-detected cameras and the ports to which they have been connected.

    ```
    gphoto2 --auto-detect
    ```

    You will see something like:

    ```
    Model                          Port                                            
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    Canon EOS 6d Mark II           usb:001,013
    ```
13. Capture the video and pipe ot out to the virtual webcam device

    ```
    gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
    ```
14. That is it. Now you can go and add it to your source in OBS.

All simple, and all free thanks to Free and Open Source Software.

Comment: Same comment as earlier. Is it possible to access the camera microphone at the same time (and make it an accessible device) ?

Comment: Thanks for this awesome tutorial. It works flawlessly on my EOS 6D. How do I make autofous work?

Comment: Thanks, key was activated v4l2loopback with parametrs max_buffers and exclusive_caps