# How to connect my camera on my computer to see the image or video in direct on my monitor?

Tags: monitor, webcam, camera

I try a lot of software and did not succeed ( I will elaborate on that latter).

I want to make video to be use latter on a internet channel. I will need to see the image on the monitor of my computer to know if the focus is good when I am making the video ( I will not be behind the camera).

- Priority: just see the image
- Bonus: make adjustment via the software

My camera is a Canon EOS Rebel T1i 500D. I know that Canon have software that could answer my need, but they ares not available for Linux.

I have the USB cable used to transfer data from my camera to my compute. Any of my computers have a HDMI input port.

The computer I use actually on witch I will make the test is:

- CPU: Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 530 @ 2.93GHz × 4
- GPU: Intel® Ironlake Desktop (integrated to the CPU)
- Memory: 6 G
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I try these software:

- Entangle: capture image but not video
- OBS: it does not support my GPU
- Shotcut: Might be possible, but if I understand well, you need a HDMI input port on the computer.
- Cheese Webcam: seems not working for external camera
- VLC:there is a function Open Capture Device ; it did not work for me

Any help or suggestion you might have are welcome!

By the way, the computer I will use in the future for my video  is a compact computer with the follow spect ; just in case that should make a big diff.

- ZOTAC ZBOX HD-AD01
- ATI RadeonTM HD 3200 GPU
- AMD AthlonTM Neo X2 L325 (1.5 GHz, dual-core)
- AMD 780E + SB710 chipset
- will be on Linux Mint MATE or xfce ( linux mint use the software library of ubuntu)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I think this is an Ubuntu question. I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: I found a way to do this via: https://askubuntu.com/a/915204/114641

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for your answer. I will look into it soon! And I agree with you, my question is relative to Ubuntu. I am using ubuntu, the tests I did was on ubuntu, it is about Ubuntu. Yes, in the future, I might go on linux mint, but now I am still on Ubuntu. However with that  attitude from the moderator community, I might change faster to a other distro . Thank but no thank for the help! ( other then from the the one that took the time to help me, and by the way, if I find a other solution, I will communicate with you Jonathan )