# Turned my DSLR into a webcam but Chrome does not recognize it

Tags: webcam, browser, ffmpeg, gphoto2

I followed [this other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856460/using-a-digital-camera-canon-as-webcam) and managed to turn my DSLR into a webcam successfully. To test it, I can see the live video in applications like `guvcview` and my DSLR is recognized as `Dummy video device (0x0000)`.

But the same device can not be found in Chrome when I try to use it as a webcam. For the record, this is how I initialize the process:

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks to @llogan, I tested with FireFox and it works there! So my problem is only with Chrome.

This is what I'm getting by running the given command:

```
$ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mjpeg @ 0x5653c54659c0] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 960x640, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[swscaler @ 0x5653c54bb000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, v4l2, to '/dev/video1':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 960x640, q=2-31, 184320 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 rawvideo
frame=  551 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:22.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.905x
```

**[UPDATE]**

As suggested by @llogan, I tested this other command:

```
$ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -c copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mjpeg @ 0x55eaeabdd900] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 960x640, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
[v4l2 @ 0x55eaeabe78c0] V4L2 output device supports only a single raw video stream
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

As you can see it did not even initialize the webcam. And to be clear about what I mean when I say it doe not work in Chrome, the webcam menu only shows my other webcam and there's no trace of my DSLR. While in FireFox, I have two webcams to select from. I also opened the developer tools in Chrome and there's no errors/warnings to help understand anything about this issue.

Comment: Do you get any error from chrome? Does it work in another browser? What does the log from ffmpeg show?

Comment: @llogan Thanks for the input. I updated my question.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i - -c copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1`. Any errors from chrome?

Comment: I'm also having the exact same error. To the link