# sudo modprobe v4l2loopback modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Bad address

Tags: 18.04

When I follow the steps of [Using a digital camera ( Canon) as webcam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856460/using-a-digital-camera-canon-as-webcam)

My linux is Ubuntu 18.04

I have an error with the following command :

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Bad address
```

I found nothing at this moment on the internet.

Could u help me ?

Eric

Comment: I only found this tag, surely a mistake. I corrected it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same thing (followed a similar guide for DSLR)
and I ended up compiling the `v4l2loopback` module and installing it.
Now everything works perfectly.

Make sure to remove the original package installation with
`sudo apt-get remove v4l2loopback-dkms`

Now follow the GitHub instructions on how to compile and install the module (really easy, clone and see the install section).
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback

Comment: thx u , I finally succeed to make it works by removing, compiling and installing it

Comment: @EricReboisson - so vote the answer :-)

Comment: I tried this and am still getting the original issue.

Answer (score 11):

When using [iriun](https://iriun.com/) for turning your iPhone cam into a webcam, the same error occured to me on Ubuntu 18.04, as it brings v4l2loopback-dkms as a dependency. So I had to first uninstall the package and its dependencies.

```
sudo apt purge v4l2loopback-dkms
```

Compiling the module is indeed getting rid of the [error](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/255).

```
git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
cd v4l2loopback
make
sudo su
make install
```

After install the command: `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1` works without issues. But to get iriun to work, I had to do these addition steps:

- Install iriun without 4l2loopback-dkms dependency:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=4l2loopback-dkms iriunwebcam.deb
  ```
- Fix dependency in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`
  Search for iriun, and remove 4l2loopback-dkms from `Depends:`

  ```
  Package: iriunwebcam
  Status: install ok installed
  Maintainer: Iriun
  Architecture: all
  Version: 2.2
  Depends: qt5-default, jackd, adb
  Description: Iriun Webcam for Linux
  ```

You could also alter the dependency in the iriunwebcam.deb file, but this way seemed easier to me.
Now iriun works great for me.

Comment: this resolved my problem

Comment: Nice solution, it worked for me, but after some time (and probably some updates) iriun stopped work and the same issue started happening again. I will follow again this tutorial and try to fix this again.

Comment: This question and these answers were really helpful to get Iriun back working for me. Wish I could do more than just upvote. 
Here's an Ansible role that installs Iriun for Ubuntu 18.04, now updated thanks to your contributions.
https://codeberg.org/ansible/iriun-webcam

Comment: Solved my problem twice. Thank you so much