# How to unmount camera (or keep it unmounted for gphoto purposes)

Tags: mount, nautilus, kde, webcam, camera

I'm trying to connect my canon dslr as a web cam to ubuntu following this advice: [Using a digital camera ( Canon) as webcam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856460/using-a-digital-camera-canon-as-webcam)

However, KDE Plasma keeps on mounting the camera, thus gphoto can't use it. Unmounting/ejecting it via nautilus or dolphin doesn't help. When I do so the camera is "unmounted" and the only option in the context menu is to mount it again.

However, gphoto still can't access the camera: `pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me was disabling auto mount in the KDE settings:[image: kde settings Wechselmedien]

I did so by removing the `gphoto` text, which is selected in the screenshot. I also did so in the `Mit Dateiverwaltung öffnen` entry.

I know this isn't very elegant, but it works.

---

On a side note:

Coincidentally I ran into the problem of my camera not being able to be used as a live stream camera again.

I ran `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback && gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie --debug` and the output (along many other lines) was:

```
0.089319 gp_camera_capture_preview [gphoto2-camera.c:1404](0): 'camera->functions->capture_preview ( camera, file, context)' failed: -6
FEHLER: Film Aufnehme Fehler ... Beenden.
```

I scrolled further up and noticed some other device being listed there as well:

```
0.062068 gp_camera_set_abilities     (2): Setting abilities ('Samsung Galaxy models (MTP)')...
0.062079 gp_setting_set              (2): Setting key 'model' to value 'Samsung Galaxy models (MTP)' (gphoto2)
```

Then I realized that this must be a smartphone I also had connected via USB to my pc, which I almost forgot about. I unplugged it and the gphoto2 command worked again as usual.